# Error 2 The system cannot find the file specified in Sublime Text 2, Windows 8

Tags: build, compiler-errors, sublimetext2

Just installed Sublime Text 2, try to build hello world program, and get this message:

```
[Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
[cmd:  [u'g++', u'', u'-o', u'/']]
[dir:  C:\Windows\system32]
[path: C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\]
[Finished]
```

What do I need to do to compile a program correctly in ST2?

Comment: See [Build systems in Sublime Text](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11729368/build-systems-in-sublime-text).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved.  Sublime Text 2 needs g++, bash, etc in order to compile. These files (?) need to be installed in your computer, as per the instructions on this page:

http://www.claremontmckenna.edu/pages/faculty/alee/g++/g++.html

Make sure you save the file you're working on, where ever on your drive before building and running.