# R not working with Sublime Text2

Tags: r, sublimetext2, sublimerepl

I am trying to get R 2.15.3 to work with Sublime Text 2. I followed the steps in http://tomschenkjr.net/using-sublime-text-2-for-r/ . When I try `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> R`, I get a error message

```
   WindowsError(2,'The system cannot find the file specified.').
```

I have double checked and the path I have mentioned in default_extend_env is correct.

Can someone tell me what might be problem, and how I could fix this?

Comment: Does this help ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146111/error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-in-sublime-text-2-windows-8 ? maybe you need to install `g++` compiler.

Answer (score 0):

I guess this could be useful for you  http://tomschenkjr.net/using-sublime-text-2-for-r/, 
be careful that's a setting way in PC.