# SublimeREPL Unable to Find R

Tags: r, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

Okay, this is driving my crazy. I had set this up before, deleted Sublime Text, and now I can't remember what the right configuration was.

Very simple: I'm running R through SublimeREPL and need to point the REPL to where R is installed.

I followed the directions at http://sublimerepl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/, which say to go into the user-defined REPL settings and add this:

```
{
 ...
 "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "{PATH}:/home/myusername/bin"}
 ...
}
```

where the path points to the right directory. I tried replacing it with

```
{
 ...
 "default_extend_env": {"PATH": "C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin"}
 ...
}
```

and it's still unable to find R, plus now it's giving me the error:

```
Error trying to parse settings: Expected value in Packages\User\SublimeREPL.sublime-     settings:2:2
```

I know this is an easy fix. Can anybody point out what I'm doing wrong here?

---

*I'm using Sublime Text 3. I previously had this working, but on Sublime Text 2.

- I've been to http://tomschenkjr.net/using-sublime-text-2-for-r/ and the piece where he mentions "pointing SublimeREPL at R" ... he doesn't include the actual code, as far as I can see
- I've also seen this thread [Error 2 The system cannot find the file specified in Sublime Text 2, Windows 8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13146111/error-2-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified-in-sublime-text-2-windows-8), but I had it working before and didn't have to do anything along those lines

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Go to `Preferences -> Browse Packages...` and create a directory tree `User/SublimeREPL/config/R`. In that directory, create a new file named `Main.sublime-menu` with the following contents:

```json
[
     {
        "id": "tools",
        "children":
        [{
            "caption": "SublimeREPL",
            "mnemonic": "r",
            "id": "SublimeREPL",
            "children":
            [
                {"command": "repl_open",
                 "caption": "Rterm",
                 "id": "repl_r",
                 "mnemonic": "r",
                 "args": {
                    "type": "subprocess",
                    "external_id": "r",
                    "additional_scopes": ["tex.latex.knitr"],
                    "encoding": {"windows": "$win_cmd_encoding"},
                    "soft_quit": "\nquit(save=\"no\")\n",
                    "cmd": {"windows": ["C:/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin/x64/Rterm.exe", "--ess", "--encoding=$win_cmd_encoding"]},
                    "cwd": "$file_path",
                    "extend_env": {"windows": {"PATH": "{PATH}:/C/Program Files/R/R-3.0.2/bin"}},
                    "cmd_postfix": "\n",
                    "suppress_echo": {"windows": false},
                    "syntax": "Packages/R/R.tmLanguage"
                    }
                }
            ]
        }]
    }
]
```

Save the file, and you should now have a `Tools -> SublimeREPL -> Rterm` menu option. Double-check that the path is the correct one to the `Rterm.exe` file. On my computer (32-bit XP) it's in the `i386` subfolder of `bin`, so yours may be in `bin/x64` or something like that.

I hope this helps, let me know if you still have issues.

Comment: Thanks! I'm running into major issues with this. 1) When I go to Preferences --> Browse Packages, there are two folders: One for User and another for SublimeREPL. So the SublimeREPL folder isn't in the User folder. So I created another path under User, as you described, and added the Main.sublime-menu file with those contents. But when I load Sublime afterwards, R is not even an option under SublimeREPL. 2) Rather than creating a new path as you mentioned, I just went and moved the SublimeREPL folder (that already has all the User/SublimeREPL/config stuff in it) into the "User" path

Comment: @MarcTulla - don't move, just copy.

Comment: @MarcTulla I made a minor mistake in my answer, there won't be a separate `R` submenu, but you should have an `Rterm` option if you created `User/SublimeREPL/config/R/Main.sublime-menu` with the contents I gave you. Is that not showing up?

Comment: Please [join me in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45232/21115295) so we don't clutter the comments with troubleshooting...

Comment: In more recent versions of R, maybe only 64bit builds, there is only `R.exe`

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this by adding the location of Rterm.exe to PATH