# Error in SublimeREPL to debug python

Tags: python, sublimetext3, sublimerepl

OS:Windows 10
software：Sublime Text 3
I am running Python with SublimeREPL and it return me the error as following:

> error: FileNotFoundError(2, 'The system cannot find the file specified.', None, 2)

I have followed the steps [SublimeREPL Unable to Find R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21115295/sublimerepl-unable-to-find-r)

there is another error:

> reloading settings Packages/User/SublimeREPL.sublime-settings
>   error: Error trying to parse settings: Invalid escape in Packages\User\SublimeREPL.sublime-settings:2:32

how can I solve it and finally to finish setting up the packages????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah,I`ve alread solved the problem from [Sublime2 and SublimeREPL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21290224/sublime2-and-sublimerepl)

Just try to edit the path again as below:
you'll need to modify {"PATH":"{PATH};c:\Python32"} to {"PATH":"{PATH};c:\Python32;c:\path\to\R"}